# In Ruby, why does !nil return => true?

Tags: ruby, object, null

If you do this:

```
    $ nil
    => nil
```

But if you do this:

```
    $ !nil
    => true
```

Why is !nil true?

Comment: What else can it be? `true` is the most reasonable candidate for non-falsy values. It comes from the definition.

Comment: What did you expect it to do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you use a boolean operator like `!` on an object in Ruby the object must first be converted, behind the scenes, to a boolean value (`true` or `false`). Every object in Ruby is either "truthy" or "falsy," and Ruby's implementors have chosen for `nil` to be falsy, so `!nil` is equivalent to `!false`, which evaluates to `true`.

Comment: It's probably easier to say it "evaluates as true" or "evaluates as false" when used as an expression. It's this behavior that allows `!!` to be used to render things into boolean values. `!nil` is `true` and `!!nil` is `false`.

Answer (score 4):

The `!` operator is unary boolean NOT. It will return `true` if its operand is `nil` or `false`. Otherwise it will return `false`.

```
!nil # => true
!false # => true
!Object.new # => false
```

In boolean expression Ruby always consider `nil` and `false` as `false` and all the rest values as `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Because in general, comparisons, nil is regarded as **false**, so, if you do:

```
if something_that_returns_nil
  puts "did not return nil"
else
  puts "returned nil"
```

You would expect it to have the inverse behavior if it was:

```
if !something_that_returns_nil
  puts "did return nil"
else
  puts "did not return nil"
```

So, when you "invert" nil it becomes false as there isn't an specific object that represents **not_being_nil** (as not being nil is any value in Ruby).